# Scraping site with Request and Cheerio gets strange html content

Tags: javascript, node.js, web-scraping, httprequest

I'm trying to scrape a simple website with Cheerio and Request

Here is my code:

```
import request from 'request';
request('http://michaelhyatt.com/page/2', function(err, res, html) {
  console.log(html);
});
```

But the HTML that I get back is gibberish, some kind of weird encoded content:

```
���r� �lE�?��iSZb�,�DI�<��[k��-yy��v(@H�U������nE��y��y��9;��D����S֗�����M�duϲ�M�
H$�D"3��x����gg?�{����:�z���v�����4��7�c |���&����V��ڇ␌��3⎼�┌["�:��
```

What am I doing wrong? Other websites I have tried to scrape do not experience this issue.

Comment: Does [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/22027928/771848) or [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/23406813/771848) help?

Comment: You are my hero @alecxe

Comment: Possible duplicate of [nodejs encoding using request](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12040643/nodejs-encoding-using-request)

Answer (score 1):

I solve the same issue with axios, by just disable encoding on headers by:

```
            const response = await axios.get(baseUrl, {
                headers: {
                    "Accept-Encoding" : null
                }
            });
            console.log(response)
```

The answer was found from the comments above from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12040643/nodejs-encoding-using-request/22027928#22027928)

Comment: THANK GOD! I LOOK FOR THIS ANSWER FOR HOURS!