# Node.js request module returns unicode characters

Tags: node.js, express, npm-request

I'm using the `request` module and I'm getting a status code of `200` but the body looks like this: `��N�0��w9׃t�"���M�� c� ��@\�=���c���}�_YR���c�cߦZ�#�&�Z�~��m�F���+e�{s���gR/����Z�����f7)����Hq�3h��` ... how can I fix it to return a `json` response?

This is my code:

```
module.exports.userCreate = function(req, res, next) {
  var user = new User();
  var username = req.body.username;
  var password = req.body.password;

  user.username = username;
  user.password = password;

  var payload = {    
    "username": username,
    "password": password
  }
  var options = {
    'method': 'post',
    'body': payload,
    'content-type': 'application/json',
    'json': true,
    'url': "https://example.com/api/login"
  }
  request(options, function (error, response, body) {
    console.log(response.statusCode);
    if (!error && response.statusCode == 200) {
      console.log(body);
    }
    else if(error) {
      return done(err);
    }
    else if(response.statusCode == 401) {
      return done(null, false, req.flash('loginMessage', 'No user Found'));
    }
  });
}
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8332500/module-request-how-to-properly-retrieve-accented-characters  .. check this

Comment: That looks too garbled even for mojibake, try it after adding gzip: true to your options.

Comment: @RïshïKêshKümar that doesn't helps..

Comment: @AlexK. thank you, it works with gzip: true option

Comment: @AlexK. u are good of programing, just save me as well