# how to retrieve accented characters on express?

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, mockserver

I have problems with accented characters on my POST request ..
I tryed with iconv but noways..
Part of my code:

**Edit:**
...

```
    var bodyString = JSON.stringify(req.body);

    var options = {
        host: XXXXX,
        port: XXX,
        path: url,
        method: 'POST',
        encoding: null,
        rejectUnauthorized: false,

        headers: {
            "OAM_SFID": header.sfid,
            "X-FORWARDED-SERVER": header.server,
            "OAM_TIENE_PERFIL": header.loginType,
            "OAM_REMOTE_USER": header.user,
            "Content-Type": "application/json;charset=UTF-8",
            'Content-Length': bodyString.length,
            "Accept": "application/json"
        }
    };
    var body = '';
    var getReq = https.request(options, function (res) {
        console.log("\nstatus code: ", res.statusCode); // CODE 400! -.-
        var currentHeader = res.headers['content-type']; 
        res.setEncoding('utf8');
        res.on('data', function (data) {//this data has a accented character
          console.log(data);// Expected a ',' or '}' at character 1132
        body += data;
        });

        res.on('end', function () {
            var parsed = currentHeader && currentHeader.indexOf('json') != -1 ? JSON.parse(body) : body;
            response.status(res.statusCode);
            response.send(parsed);
            if(res.statusCode === 200){
             .....
```

I saw this post [Module request how to properly retrieve accented characters? � � �](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8332500/module-request-how-to-properly-retrieve-accented-characters) but doesnt work..

My node version is 9.6.1
The problem is on the body where there are a word with accent this do an 400 error ,   -> Expected a ',' or '}' at character 1132

Comment: can we have an example of whats returned

Comment: the problem is when i send on the body a character witth one accent the response is Expected a ',' or '}' at character 1132
A good response is JSON ..

Comment: Yeah but you can JSON.parse

Comment: res.on('data', function (data) {
       //here data is  Expected a ',' or '}' at character 1132 becuase the accent character , cant read it
       body += data;
        });

Comment: Can you post a sample of the response? Without trying to parse it? It will help testing any solutions that might show up.

Answer (score 0):

According to current node.js documentation you may need the following

```
res.setEncoding('utf8');
```

So that your code looks like:

```
var getReq = https.request(options, function (res) {
    var currentHeader = res.headers['content-type']; 
    res.setEncoding('utf8');  // new line!

    res.on('data', function (data) {
    body += data;
    });
```

You can see the example here: https://nodejs.org/dist/latest-v8.x/docs/api/http.html#http_http_get_options_callback

Comment: mm testing with that doesnt work , if i put that, data will be a string and then this do an error ->  Expected a ',' or '}' at character 1132
Data contais the  character with accent :(